# Eliza was here or Eliza has been here

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

There is a resort review site called "Eliza was here". Could it just as well be called "Eliza has been here" without change in meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of a resort review, there is little difference between simple past **was** present perfect **has been**.

In other circumstances, the present perfect normally indicates that something happened in past has some effect that lasts to the present, for example you would say "I have reserved a room" rather than "I reserved a room" to indicate that the reservation is still in effect.

In the context of visiting a place, the lasting effect is that you can cross that place off your list of places to visit.

> Q: Have you ever been to Paris?
>   A: Yes, I have [been to Paris] - *and I have crossed it off my  list*

You would only normally use past simple for visiting a place if you were there at a particular (specified) time, for example:

> I **was** in Berlin **when the wall came down**.